# Using probablePrime to generate prime number. probablePrime(512, randomSeed);

Tags: java, lotus-notes, biginteger

I am trying to generate a random prime number using probablePrime method of BigInteger class. this is a lotus notes version 6.5 agent that i am trying to work on.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

    public class RSA{

        public static BigInteger genPrimeNum(int bitlen, Random random){
            return BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlen, random);
            }

    }
```

When compiling I get error saying method probablePrime(int, java.util.Random) not found in class BigInteger

Please help.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

[`probablePrime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#probablePrime%28int,%20java.util.Random%29) has been in Java since version 1.4. Is it possible that your environment uses an earlier version of Java?

Comment: yes it is..Its 1.3. Now I want to use java 1.6 with lotus Notes 6.5. Is there a way to do that..?

Comment: @Himanshu.MarJAVA: No idea, I'm afraid - I haven't used Lotus Notes.

Comment: even i am new to it....well where there is a will there is a way.. I will find any solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Notes to the latest version.